# Bash: total size of file in current directory matching regular expression

Tags: bash, shell, sh

```
ls | grep -P "$1" | awk '{ x += $5 } END { print "total bytes:" x }'
```

This code is returning 0 using "[0-9]" as reg expr, in current folder there are 2 files named: "1" and "6", each one with size of 138bytes.

Anyone could help me to find the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just missing the `-l` option to `ls`.

```
ls -l | grep -P "$1" | awk '{ x += $5 } END { print "total bytes:" x }'
```

Comment: this line, with an argument like [0-9] is returning the size of all the file in the current directory. any suggestion about how to filter files from a reg expr?

Comment: @AntonioFalcone : isn't it what the `grep -P "$1"` is supposed to filter out already?

Comment: This is the shit! Works like a charm, man I didn't know AWK is this powerful, almost feel like i'm watchin' the matrix screen now - heheheh :-P

:-)

Answer (score 1):

`du` can help you with this; it has a `-c` flag for displaying a "grand total". It results in a final line containing the total size followed by the word total. Therefore, the following should give you the total size in bytes for your selection:

```
du -bc yourFilePattern | awk 'END {print $1}'
```

EDIT:

If something like `*pattern*` is not enough and you want a regex, just use:

```
ls | grep -P "$regex" | xargs du -bc | awk 'END {print $1}'
```

Comment: `du` counts file blocks, not bytes, unless you use `--apparent-size -b`.

Comment: @Barmar: I added the `-b` flag to have the output in bytes. Thanks !

Comment: You also need `--apparent-size`.

Comment: @Barmar: `-b` seems to be "equivalent to '--apparent-size --block-size=1'"

Comment: You can drop `tail -1` by doing `awk 'END{print $1}'`

Comment: how can i use it with a regular expression?