# Adding up file sizes in bash shells

Tags: bash, file, shell, loops, addition

I've written a shell script that takes a directory as an arg and prints the file names and sizes, I wanted to find out how to add up the file sizes and store them so that I can print them after the loop. I've tried a few things but haven't gotten anywhere so far, any ideas?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Directory <$1> contains the following files:"
let "x=0"
TEMPFILE=./count.tmp
echo 0 > $TEMPFILE
ls $1 |
while read file
do
        if [ -f $1/$file ]
        then
                echo "file: [$file]"
        stat -c%s $file > $TEMPFILE
        fi
cat $TEMPFILE
done
echo "number of files:"
cat ./count.tmp
```

Help would be thoroughly appreciated.

Comment: Ufff, you are parsing `ls`, storing in a tempfile that you then print. .. I would suggest to use `du`, which shows the sizes of the files and the directory itself.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your script question, but 'du -c' will do this for you.

Comment: Googling showed a host of possible duplicates, including [Bash: total size of file in current directory matching regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690431/bash-total-size-of-file-in-current-directory-matching-regular-expression)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A number of issues in your code:

- [Don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- [Quote variables in large majority of cases](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting)
- Don't use temp files when they're not needed
- Use already made tools like [du](/questions/tagged/du) for this (see comments)

Assuming you're just wanting to get practice at this and/or want to do something else other than what [du](/questions/tagged/du) already does, you should change syntax to something like

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="$1"
[[ $dir == *'/' ]] || dir="$dir/"
if [[ -d $dir ]]; then
  echo "Directory <$1> contains the following files:"
else
  echo "<$1> is not a valid directory, exiting"
  exit 1
fi

shopt -s dotglob
for file in "$dir"*; do
  if [[ -f $file ]]; then
    echo "file: [$file]"
    ((size+=$(stat -c%s "$file")))
  fi
done

echo "$size"
```

Note:

- You don't have to pre-allocate variables in bash, `$size` is assumed to be 0
- You can use `(())` for math that doesn't require decimal places.
- You can use globs (`*`) to get all files (including dirs, symlinks, etc...) in a particular directory (and globstar `**` for recursive)
- `shopt -s dotglob` Is needed so it includes hidden `.whatever` files in glob matching.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ls -l` to find size of files:

```
echo "Directory $1 contains the following:"
size=0
for f in "$1"/*; do
    if [[ ! -d $f ]]; then
        while read _ _ _ _ bytes _; do
            if [[ -n $bytes ]]; then
                ((size+=$bytes))
                echo -e "\tFile: ${f/$1\//} Size: $bytes bytes"
            fi
        done < <(ls -l "$f")
    fi
done
echo "$1 Files total size: $size bytes"
```

Parsing `ls` results for size is ok here as byte size will always be found in the 5th field.

If you know what the date stamp format for `ls` is on your system and portability isn't important, you can parse `ls` to reliably find both the size and file in a single `while read` loop.

```
echo "Directory $1 contains the following:"
size=0
while read _ _ _ _ bytes _ _ _ file; do
    if [[ -f $1/$file ]]; then
        ((size+=$bytes))
        echo -e "\tFile: $file Size: $bytes bytes"
    fi
done < <(ls -l "$1")
echo "$1 Files total size: $size bytes"
```

Note: These solutions would not include hidden files.  Use `ls -la` for that.

Depending on the need or preference, `ls` can also print sizes in a number of different formats using options like `-h` or `--block-size=SIZE`.

Comment: Don't parse ls, see first bullet in my answer.

Comment: @BroSlow The link you posted mentions the only reason not to parse `ls -l` for size is because date formats are not consistent across platforms.  The way my solution reads using an array makes the date format irrelevant.

Comment: There are a number of reasons not to parse `ls`, e.g. in the particular cases your example won't work correctly if a file has a space in it.

Comment: @BroSlow Yes, please see updated answer.  `ls` can be parsed reliably for specific needs.

Comment: Not debating that `ls` can be parsed correctly (though there's almost never a need). But you're not doing it correctly. Just test it, there is no way it can differentiate between a filename with a space and two seperate filenames in either case you list.

Comment: If you know the number of preceding lines like in this case, you can set your target `read` variable to be the following field, and the variable (f in script #2) will contain all fields through the end of the line.  Both scripts should work now.

Comment: You should quote `$1`, but otherwise I can't think of a reasonable case to break it now, assuming a user hasn't overloaded `ls` or `ls -l`, so +1

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Directory <$1> contains the following files:"

find ${1}/* -prune -type f -ls | \
    awk '{print; SIZE+=$7} END {print ""; print "total bytes: " SIZE}'
```

Use *find* with *-prune* (so it does not recurse into subdirectories) and *-type f* (so it will only list files and no symlinks or directories) and *-ls* (so it lists the files).

Pipe the output into awk and

for each line print the whole line (*print*; replace with `print $NF` to only print the last item of each line, which is the filename including the directory). Also add the value of the 7th field, which is the file size (in my version of find) to the variable SIZE.

After all lines have been processed (*END*) print the calculated total size.